# Cant output the value for when a test is invalid

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Multiples {

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    int number;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("insert a number >");
    number = kb.nextInt();

    if (number >= 0 && number <= 100)
      if (number % 7 == 0)
        System.out.println("multiple of 7");
      else 
        System.out.println("not a multiple of 7");
      if (number % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println(" multiple of 2");
      else
        System.out.println("not a multiple of 2");
    else
      System.out.println("choose a different number");
  }

}
```

The code is working right until the last moment. All if statements work inside the main IF in which the test is accepted. But I get a syntax error when i use the last else. Could anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Use some brackets... You want to have two statements in your top `if`.

Comment: From the doc : _"Deciding when to omit the braces is a matter of personal taste. Omitting them can make the code more brittle. If a second statement is later added to the "then" clause, a common mistake would be forgetting to add the newly required braces. **The compiler cannot catch this sort of error; you'll just get the wrong results.**"_

Comment: Even a code formatter would have shown you this error, but this is one example of why you should always use brackets.

Comment: Sincere apologies now I understood the error.

Answer (score 5):

You will want to add brackets in the top-most `if`

```
if (number >= 0 && number <= 100) {
    if (number % 7 == 0)
        System.out.println("multiple of 7");
    else 
        System.out.println("not a multiple of 7");
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println(" multiple of 2");
    else
        System.out.println("not a multiple of 2");
} else
    System.out.println("choose a different number");
```

An `if` block requires curly `{}` brackets if you want more than one statement to be executed as part of its body. In your case, you have 2 `if-else` statements. You therefore need the braces.

Otherwise it is equivalent to

```
if (number >= 0 && number <= 100) {
    if (number % 7 == 0)
        System.out.println("multiple of 7");
    else 
        System.out.println("not a multiple of 7");
}
if (number % 2 == 0)
    System.out.println(" multiple of 2");
else
    System.out.println("not a multiple of 2");

else
    System.out.println("choose a different number");
```

And the last `else` doesn't have a corresponding `if`, which is syntactically incorrect in Java.

We all recommend you always use brackets regardless of the number of statements you want to execute in your `if-else` blocks.

Comment: Better to use brackets on all the `if`s.